# Data types in Microsoft Access designer

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

In Microsoft Access 2013, we can use Char, Text and Memo as data types of table columns if we write DDL statements. But in its designer just Short Text and Long Text data types are available. Short Text is equal to Text and Long Text is equal to Memo.

How can I define a column of type Char using Microsoft Access designer?

Comment: Text in access equals varchar

Comment: You can't. Access will always strip trailing spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain that Jet doesn't deal in Char.  In fact, I see no evidence of a Char data type in this page from a book on MSAccess:

[Microsoft Access 2013 - Level 1](https://books.google.com/books?id=8aK-CQAAQBAJ&pg=PA4&lpg=PA4&dq=ms%20access%202013%20data%20types&source=bl&ots=jPVVMpJoio&sig=OzoR6tnv2So6w9PrqyS8IhOsrPA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAzgUahUKEwjPncvB6NPIAhUD8z4KHY83AKc#v=onepage&q=ms%20access%202013%20data%20types&f=false)

To the best of my knowledge, you would use ShortText as the datatype in cases where you would normally use Char in SQL Server.